# java sending wireless messages between applications

Tags: java, wireless, java-wireless-toolkit

I want to create two Java applications that will be able to send message to each other wirelessly. The two applications does not need to be in different machines, since this is only a simulation so I hope to run it in the same machine. Is there a way to do that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a connection with **socket**, or with **RMI**.

If I remember right, the RMI is newer than socket..

However you can find there about socket: [All About Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/)

and here: [About RMI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/)

Comment: Oh yes thank you, I always think about Java Wireless API but forgot the RMI :D